NextJS - Update data object being passed into Child Component based on Button Click
I need to know how to update a data object based on a button click. This data object is being passed into a Child Component. When a user chooses an option in the dropdown menu, I want to populate that data object based on the key of the chosen option in the dropdown menu.
Here is my Parent Component...
<div>
        <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTrigger>
                <Button variant="bordered">
                    Films
                </Button>
            </DropdownTrigger>
            <DropdownMenu
                variant="faded"
                aria-label="Dropdown menu with description"
            >
                <DropdownSection title="Shorts"> 
                
                {films.shorts.map((film) => (
                    <DropdownItem
                        key={film.key}
                        textValue={film.key}
                        onAction={(key) => showFilm(key)}
                    >
                        {film.name} {film.year}
                    </DropdownItem>
                ))}
                
                </DropdownSection>
            </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
        
        {shown && <Film data={data} />}
    </div>

My Child Component is <Film>. I am passing the data object into it.
I'm calling the function showFilm(key) when an option is clicked in the dropdown menu.
What I need to know is how do I get the Child Component to update with new data if I update that data in the showFilm() function?
I tried updating the data object when the showFilm() function is called, but the Child Component doesn't receive the updated data. I need the Child Component to be refreshed so it receives the new data object (that has been updated).
const [shown, setShown] = useState(false);
  
let data;

function showFilm(key) {
    setShown(true)
    // here is where I want to update the data object being passed into the Child Component. I want the data object to equal the key of the option that was clicked.
    data = key;
    console.log("data", data, "key", key)
  }


define a state in order to store  data in it and pass state to child component
!!notice that when state changes in parent component, both child and parent components are re-render as well.
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
function showFilm(key) {
    setShown(true)
    data = key;
    console.log("data", data, "key", key)
    setData(key);
}


pass data to child component
{shown && <Film data={data} />}


data = key; will produce an error here.  Even if one corrects that error, re-assigning and/or mutating state in React is considered a bug.

You're not using state.
Observe the difference between the two values you're tracking here:
const [shown, setShown] = useState(false);

let data;

One is using state, the other is not.  So updating one will cause components to re-render, updating the other will not.  In fact, as soon as anything else causes the component to re-render (such as updating the shown state), the changes will be lost because on render the data variable is re-declared and has no value set.
Track the value in state:
const [shown, setShown] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState();

And update that state:
setData(key);

